# Guide на русском о Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript, java, actionscript-3

Посоветуйте пару хороших гайдов/книг о Actionscript 3. Знаю Java на уровне Junior`a , синтаксис Actionscript 3 не совсем понятен, хотя весьма похож. Гуглил, яндексил, но натыкался или на "уроки доступны только зарегестрированных пользователям" или на другой шлак. Хорошего не нашел. 
П.с. английский знаю на среднем уровне, читаю, но иногда приходится подглядывать в словарь. Пока хочется прочитать информацию на русском, а уже потом переходить на английский

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActionScript 3.0 для Flash. Подробное руководство. Колин Мук.](http://easyflash.org/flashlearn/flashbooks/144-actionscript-3.0-dlja-flash.-podrobnoe.html)

Answer (score 2):

Лотт Дж„ Шалл Д., Питере К, 
ActionScript 3.0. Сборник рецептов. - Пер. с англ. - СПб: Символ-Плюс, 2007. - 
608 с, ил.

Answer (score 0):

Вот - http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html - использую чаще всего. Особо полезен, если подключить его к IntelliJ IDEA.

Но сначала надо Колина Мука почитать, да.